# Complete a function to check if ascending is true. No idea what I am doing wrong

Tags: python

```
def sortList(mylist, ascending):
 enter code here

# expected output: [4, 12, 19, 33]
print(sortList([19,4,33,12], True))

# expected output: [33, 19, 12, 4]
print(sortList([19,4,33,12], False))
```

Comment: To begin with, you would have to actually provide some code for the `sortList` function.

Comment: Your post includes code only, please provide some explanation of your problem.

Comment: `enter code here` is (unsurprisingly) not valid Python code.

Comment: If your question contains your full attempt, it would appear that what you're doing wrong is that you haven't done anything to complete your assignment. If you have a specific question about why your attempts to solve the problem have failed, then you need to demonstrate what you've attempted and the problem you're having with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to check if a list is sorted in ascending order:

```
def is_ascending(l):    
    return all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in range(len(l) - 1))
```

Or you can do this if you need a variable that tells if the list must be sorted or not:

```
def is_ascending(l, must_be_sorted):       
        return not (all(l[i] <= l[i+1] for i in range(len(l) - 1)) ^ must_be_sorted)
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why I should get negative reputation for an answer that doesn't seem so bad to me.